# What is the keyboard shortcut for minimizing a normal window?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut for minimizing a normal window?

Comment: it is in windows itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified what operating system.  But in Windows it is Windows-M.

Comment: Note that if you have multiple windows open, this minimizes _all_ of them.

Answer (score 7):

I generally use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, followed by <kbd>n</kbd> to minimize the current window.

Answer (score 3):

minimizing is

1. <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>down arrow key</kbd>
2. <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>d key</kbd>/<kbd>m key</kbd>
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> + <kbd>N key</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you havent specified the Operating System. But for Windows 7 its <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> for maximization and  <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> for minimization. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I just tested this on Windows XP SP3 and it does not work. -1

Comment: This works on Windows 7. The poster should edit his post to specify that. (Not sure about Vista.)

Comment: That works *only* on Windows 7. There is no keyboard shortcut to do a single window at a time in XP without the help of a 3rd party tool. (Yes, you can use Alt+Space, n - but that's not really a shortcut, just using accelerator keys).

Comment: On Windows 7, WinKey + Down Arrow only returns a maximized window to normal size. You have to press it when a window is normal size to minimize.